# What is the passthrough used for in alpakka-kafka connector while producing messages?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka-stream, reactive, alpakka

This is the code for producing a single message to Kafka given in the doc https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/producer.html

```
val single: ProducerMessage.Envelope[KeyType, ValueType, PassThroughType] =
  ProducerMessage.single(
    new ProducerRecord("topicName", key, value),
    passThrough
  )
```

Could you please explain what is passThrough used for?

Answer (score 3):

`passThrough` is an additional value which comes to be available for use in `ProducerMessage.Results`’s `passThrough()`.

As the [official documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/producer.html#producer-as-a-flow) states, the best and the most widely used practice is to use this value as a transport to passing the `CommittableOffset` to a downstream `Committer.Sink`.

This seems convenient in cases when you are using a `CommittableSource` along with the `enable.auto.commit` Kafka consumer option set to `false`. In such cases you have to commit Kafka offsets manually as you processing them. I in particular use such approach when reading records from one Kafka topic, processing them and then sending them to another Kafka topic.

Here is a simple use case:

```
Consumer
      .committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(topicIn))
      .mapAsync { msg ⇒
        process(msg.record.value).map {
          response ⇒
            ProducerMessage.single(
              new ProducerRecord(topicOut, msg.record.key, response),
              passThrough = msg.committableOffset
            )
        }
      }
      .via(Producer.flexiFlow(producerSettings))
      .map(_.passThrough) // extract the passThrough
      .toMat(Committer.sink(committerSettings))(Keep.both) // commiting offsets
      .mapMaterializedValue(DrainingControl.apply)
      .run()
```